# Cannot find symbol class stream

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm trying to use `stream` package with Android Studio. I was having jdk1.7.0_79.  It gave me this error :

> Error:(11, 17) error: cannot find symbol class stream

So I updated jdk to jdk1.8.0_45

I also deleted .iml files and .idea folder and reimported project. But I still get this error. How can I get rid of this error? Thanks.

Comment: IMO, Android doesn't support Java 8...

Comment: @ShmilTheCat so do you have any idea on how to use stream? Thanks.

Comment: @jason what Shmil is saying is that you can't.  No way, no how.